# Python: why is mock not called in this instance of loop?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following test code:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "any_recordings,any_transcriptions,returns_recording,duration,exception",
    [
        (
            True,
            True,
            True,
            60,
            None
        ),
        (
            True,
            True,
            False,
            121,
            RecordingLengthException,
        ),
        (
            True,
            True,
            False,
            1,
            RecordingLengthException,
        ),
        (
            False,
            False,
            False,
            None,
            timer.Timeout,
        ),
        (
            True,
            False,
            False,
            0,
            NotTranscribedException,
        ),
    ],
)
async def test_10_mock_wait_for_recording_result(
    twilio_mock_testing: Twilio,
    any_recordings: bool,
    any_transcriptions: bool,
    returns_recording: bool,
    duration: int,
    exception: Optional[Exception],
):
    with mock.patch("twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.recording.transcription.TranscriptionInstance") as transcription_instance:
        transcription_instance.transcription_text = "Hello there."
    with mock.patch("twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.recording.RecordingInstance") as recording_instance:
        recording_instance.call_sid = "54321"
        recording_instance.date_created = datetime.datetime.now()
        recording_instance.price = "1.25"
        recording_instance.source = "whatever"
        recording_instance.transcriptions.list.return_value = [transcription_instance] if any_transcriptions else []
        recording_instance.duration = duration
        recording_instance.uri = "http://possu.xyz"
        recording_instance.status = CallStatusFinal.COMPLETED.value
        twilio_mock_testing.client.recordings.list.return_value = [recording_instance] if any_recordings else []
    on_transcribed: Callable[[Call, Recording], Any] = mock.Mock(return_value=None)
    with mock.patch.object(timer, 'Timer') as t:
        t.loop = mock.MagicMock(return_value=True)
    with pytest.raises(exception) if exception is not None else nullcontext():
        recording = twilio_mock_testing.wait_for_recording_result(
            call=Call(
                sid="54321",
                direction="abc",
                to="1234567890",
                from_="9876543210",
                status=CallStatusRunning.IN_PROGRESS.value,
                start_time=datetime.datetime.now(),
                end_time=None,
                duration=None,
                price=None,
                caller_name=None,
            ),
            raise_on_timeout=True,
            on_transcribed=on_transcribed
        )
        twilio_mock_testing.client.recordings.list.assert_called()
        if returns_recording:
            assert recording.status == CallStatusFinal.COMPLETED.value
            on_transcribed.assert_called_once()
        else:
            on_transcribed.assert_not_called()
        t.loop.assert_called()
```

Inside `wait_for_recording_result` it uses a library `timer.Timer.loop` method (which is being mocked):

```py
    def wait_for_recording_result(
        self, *, call: Call, raise_on_timeout=False, on_transcribed: Callable[[Call, Recording], Any] = None
    ):
        recording_timer = timer.Timer(timeout=60, sleep=5, what="call recording")
        recording = None
        try:
            while recording_timer.loop(raise_timeout=raise_on_timeout):
                recordings = list(self.recordings(call_sid=call.sid))
                if any(recordings):
                    recording = recordings[0]
                    if (
                        recording.duration <= 2 or recording.duration >= 120
                    ):  # See https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/13617
                        raise RecordingLengthException(recording)
                    if any(recording.transcriptions):
                        break
        catch timer.Timeout:
            ...
```

All the test cases pass, except for the first test case on `t.loop.assert_called()` and the fourth test case seems to wait for the 60 second timeout (even though loop is mocked):

```
tests/integrations/test_twilio.py::test_10_mock_wait_for_recording_result[True-True-True-60-None] FAILED
tests/integrations/test_twilio.py::test_10_mock_wait_for_recording_result[True-True-False-121-RecordingLengthException] PASSED
tests/integrations/test_twilio.py::test_10_mock_wait_for_recording_result[True-True-False-1-RecordingLengthException] PASSED
tests/integrations/test_twilio.py::test_10_mock_wait_for_recording_result[False-False-False-None-Timeout] PASSED
tests/integrations/test_twilio.py::test_10_mock_wait_for_recording_result[True-False-False-0-NotTranscribedException] PASSED

FAILED tests/integrations/test_twilio.py::test_10_mock_wait_for_recording_result[True-True-True-60-None] - AssertionError: Expected 'loop' to have been called.
```

How is it that the mock is called in every other circumstance, yet it still waits for 60 seconds on the 4th case, while claiming the mock was not called in the first case?

The only thing the **init** does of timer.Timer that I can think may cause it is `self._event = threading.Event()`, but this I can't see used anywhere except inside the `loop` method, meaning it should not be called as it is mocked.

I should also note that `timer.Timeout` is a custom exception, from the same `timer` package, inheriting from `Exception` so it isn't part of built-in python.

`twilio_mock_testing` merely creates a mock for `client` property of this `Twilio` package and not of any of the methods such as `wait_for_recording_result`...

```py
with mock.patch("twilio.rest.Client"):
    return Twilio(sid="Hello", token="olleH")
```

I am incredibly confused by this...

Comment: Each patch is undone when the corresponding `with` statement completes. You need to do all the patching in *one* `with` statement, or nest the `with` statements.

Comment: I indented everything and the problem is still the same. Your explanation doesn't seem to  match what is seen as the other cases pass, otherwise how would t.loop be asserted as called in those cases?

Comment: Actually, you're right - with a bit of adjustment I managed to get it to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was answered by the following change based on the comment by chepner:

```py
    with mock.patch("twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.recording.transcription.TranscriptionInstance") as transcription_instance:
        transcription_instance.transcription_text = "Hello there."
        with mock.patch("twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.recording.RecordingInstance") as recording_instance:
            recording_instance.call_sid = "54321"
            recording_instance.date_created = datetime.datetime.now()
            recording_instance.price = "1.25"
            recording_instance.source = "whatever"
            recording_instance.transcriptions.list.return_value = [transcription_instance] if any_transcriptions else []
            recording_instance.duration = duration
            recording_instance.uri = "http://possu.xyz"
            recording_instance.status = CallStatusFinal.COMPLETED.value
            twilio_mock_testing.client.recordings.list.return_value = [recording_instance] if any_recordings else []
            on_transcribed: Callable[[Call, Recording], Any] = mock.Mock(return_value=None)
            with mock.patch.object(timer.Timer, 'loop') as t:
                t.side_effect = [True, False] if exception is not timer.Timeout else [True, timer.Timeout]
                with pytest.raises(exception) if exception is not None else nullcontext():
                    recording = twilio_mock_testing.wait_for_recording_result(
                        call=Call(
                            sid="54321",
                            direction="abc",
                            to="1234567890",
                            from_="9876543210",
                            status=CallStatusRunning.IN_PROGRESS.value,
                            start_time=datetime.datetime.now(),
                            end_time=None,
                            duration=None,
                            price=None,
                            caller_name=None,
                        ),
                        raise_on_timeout=True,
                        on_transcribed=on_transcribed
                    )
                    twilio_mock_testing.client.recordings.list.assert_called()
                    if returns_recording:
                        assert recording.status == CallStatusFinal.COMPLETED.value
                        on_transcribed.assert_called_once()
                    else:
                        on_transcribed.assert_not_called()
                    t.assert_called()
```